# JavaScript SDK Facebook: Writing to The Document

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Still beginner, bear with me.

I'm coming from PHP where I can just `echo <tag>$variable</tag>` but I can't quite figure out how to actually make a webpage that does stuff and displays stuff with javascript. Below, when the user is logged in I tried document.write("HI")...it didn't do anything (but I know that code was processed because I can see it in the console.

I'm clearly missing a fundamental in javascript and I can't quite figure it out. I've tried to read up on it, but I'm a bit lost.

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Web Page</h1>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
            appId      : 'xxx', // App ID
            channelUrl : 'xxx', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and connected to your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;

                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                        document.write("HI!");
                });

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                                    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                                    FB.logout(function(response) {
                                            console.log('Logged out.');
                                    });
                            });
                        } else {
                            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                        }
 }, {scope: 'email'});
            } else {

                FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                                    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                                    FB.logout(function(response) {
                                            console.log('Logged out.');
                                    });
                            });
                        } else {
                            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                        }
 }, {scope: 'email'});

            }
    })

};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));


</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        } else {

        }
```

You have nothing in the final else.  You should call FB.login() for this case.

Comment: gotcha. changed my question. is that allowed or should I have made a new one?

Comment: **Stop changing your questions after they've been answered correctly***!!!! I've now solved two of your questions (three if you could count the two correct answers in another question) and have not received any credit.  Please play by the rules.